# setting new default properties for to_xml serializer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-serialization

In Rails, I'm coding a series of controllers to generate XML. Each time I'm passing a number of properties in to to_xml like:

```
to_xml(:skip_types => true, :dasherize => false)
```

Is there a way I can set these as new default properties that will apply whenever to_xml is called in my app so that I don't have to repeat myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling to_xml on a hash or an ActiveRecord model (or something else)?

I am not that you would want to, but you can easily monkey patch to_xml and redefine it to start with those parameters.  I would suggest that you make a new method to_default_xml that simply called to_xml with the parameters you wanted

```
def to_default_xml
  self.to_xml(:skip_types => true, :dasherize => false)
end
```

Update:

Since you want to add this to a couple of ActiveRecord models you could do two things, open up ActiveRecord::base (which is a bit hackish and fragile) or create a module and import it into every model you want to use with it. A little more typing, but much cleaner code.

I would put a class in lib/ that looks something like this:

```
module DefaultXml
  def to_default_xml
    self.to_xml(:skip_types => true, :dasherize => false)
  end
end
```

Then in your models:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DefaultXml
end
```

Comment: Thanks! A wrapper method sounds like a good hack for me to use (for now). Given that I'm going to be calling this from multiple controllers (on ActiveRecord models), where would you recommend I put that code?

Answer (score 1):

I put together a plugin to handle default serialization options. Check it out at github.com/laserlemon/dry_serial/tree/master.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  dry_serial :skip_types => true, :dasherize => false
end
```

It also has support for multiple serialization styles that can be called like:

```
@my_model.to_xml(:skinny)
@my_model.to_xml(:fat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about AR's to_xml method and depending on your needs, you could get away with extending the AcitveRecord class by creating a file named: lib\class_extensions.rb

```
class ActiveRecord::Base   
   def to_xml_default
      self.to_xml(:skip_types => true, :dasherize => false)
   end
end
```

Next, put this in an initializer, so that it's included when Rails starts up:

```
require 'class_extensions'
```

Now, you can use it as follows (w/o having to specifically include it in each model):

```
MyModel.to_xml_default
```